# How to calculate android device diagonal correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, screen-size

I'm trying to calculate Android device diagonal, but i get wrong results.

I write:

```
fun getScreenInches(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float {
    return hypot( displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.xdpi, displayMetrics.heightPixels * displayMetrics.ydpi)
}
```

Before i get metrics:

```
private fun Activity.getMetrics() = DisplayMetrics().apply {
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(this)
    }
```

And i call `getScreenInches()` this way:

`getScreenInches(activity.getMetrics())`

The problem is my result more that i expecting.

I get ~8.5 inches for 7 inches device, and ~9.5 inches for 8 inches device.

I debuged my code, and what i get that
`displayMetrics.widthPixels` and `displayMetrics.heightPixels` are completly **correct**.

So i'm not sure `displayMetrics.xdpi` and `displayMetrics.ydpi` are. Seems like this values approximated to some tabular values and don't show real density.

What should i do or read to make my function return correct results?

Answer (score 0):

```
Density = sqrt((wp * wp) + (hp * hp)) / di
```

Where `wp` indicates is width Resolutions in pixels, `hp` indicates is height Resolutions in pixels and `di` is the diagonal size in inches.